# Prestashop Voucher coupon block not showing

Tags: prestashop, coupon

Although in my theme the coupon block had showed ok, now it isn't showing nothing. So the costumers can't use the voucher coupons. I add an screenshot to see what i mean. The green block i mean. [Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBGLK.png)

Comment: There is not enough meaningful information here to form a question. I am voting to close as "unclear what you're asking".

Comment: The ask is why the voucher coupon block isn't display any more.

Comment: Have you created a right voucher in backoffice?

Comment: Yes of course. The last days didn't show it.. a few days before it was ok.

Answer (score 0):

Try executing the following line of code on your store.

```
Configuration::updateGlobalValue('PS_CART_RULE_FEATURE_ACTIVE', '1');
```

You need to add it to some PHP file (PrestaShop's file) and open a page that runs that PHP file, once it will be executed you should be able to see and use the voucher field on the Checkout page.

Comment: Which php file do you mean??  It is a specific one?

Comment: Hi, By default, it is disabled in Prestashop but whenever you will add coupon code from backoffice, Prestashop will make it enable by ownself.

Answer (score 0):

Though this is an old topic, I found this with the same problem. [In our case](https://www.pecatum.com/en/) this happened when installing / updating PayPal module. The solution is to unhook PayPal module from Header hook. I know it's not a "coding solution", bugt I hope it may help someone...

The solution is not mine, I found it here: https://www.prestaforum.com/threads/un-bug-muy-comentado-en-la-1-6-0-x-cupon-descuento-vs-paypal.357/.